# Should I never rely on the datastore index to contain my data (indexed)?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

In the book [Programming Google AppEngine](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/059652272X?ie=UTF8&tag=xamde01-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=059652272X), page 181, it says:

*In rare cases, **it’s also possible** for changes to indexes to be applied prior to changes to entities, and **for the apply phase to fail and leave committed changes unapplied until the next transaction on the entity group.***

- How can I deal with these cases?
- Does my put operation get an Exception?

It seems to me I should never **rely** on the index to know my data.

Comment: The situation you described is a bug in the AppEngine which, hopefully, Google will get around to fixing.  The activity of updating a table and all associated indices should be an atomic transaction.  Any failure should result in a rollback of all changes in the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret an comment from Nick Johnson in this question [Can I have the benefit of parent-child relations without the cost of datastore contention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704068/can-i-have-the-benefit-of-parent-child-relations-without-the-cost-of-datastore-co) as: "This bug has been fixed. Problem gone. **Do** rely on the index.